# Flutter/ios: Cant get firebase messaging to work

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Im making a flutter caht app, and im trying to get push notifications to work. It works on Android, so I know the code I have is working fine: it is something specific with android. I followed firebase's steps closely, to list what I have so far:

> Xcode capabilities:
> [image]

> app bundle id is for sure the same between ios and firestore

> APN authentication key setup with team value and app key

Anything Im missing? Really no idea what it could be.

Comment: A real Apple device to test it. [iOS doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration/)

Comment: @NoobN3rd i see. So its impossible to test notifications on a simulator? I have to use a real device?

Comment: Yes if they depend on APN. Like FCM.

Comment: @NoobN3rd I'm in the same situatioin, It works on android, but not working on ios, do you manage to fix it?

Comment: @Fasikaw To test notifications from Firebase on iOS, you need to plug in your real apple product to the computer, and then run the app on that connected device. Now if you send a message let's say from Firebase console, you should get it on your device.

Comment: @NoobN3rd, What if I generate the ipa, from codemagic and test it in real device? Will it cause an issue?

Comment: @Fasikaw What do you mean? In the end it will be OK, whether you use your own computer or codemagic(another computer), when you test it on real devices, it will be OK.
For example when you create a test-flight, tester will receive the notifications.

Comment: The only thing is that while you're developing the app, you can't test/get the notifications on iOS emulators while you can on Android emulators.

Comment: I tested it in real device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for me was that I was trying to implement both an APN auth key, and APN certificate. When i changed my app through app store connect to only the auth key, it worked.

I also used a real device to test.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can check

1. Add the apns key in firebase
2. Use a real device
3. Enable push notification capability in xcode
4. Check the app in different state. Background, killed, foreground

Comment: I added the apns key, to firebase and download the googleservice-info.plist file, I enabled push notification, then I generated the ipa file on codemagic afterthat, when I test it on real device I couldn't get the notification. Any help??

Comment: Did you also add permission to get notification in ios?

Comment: yes, I added the permission and I granted the permission. but it is now showing.

Comment: If you are triggering it from a web service add priority too